# Gradle: use the bom of a dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Using gradle, in a projectA we import the resteasy BOM:

```
compile platform('com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.2')
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

Then in a projectB we import projectA

```
implementation("com.my.service:projectA:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

Now, when we compile projectB, jackson-datatype-jsr310 cannot be found. It cannot determine the version to use. Same if in projectB I want to import another jackson dependencies, that are defined in the BOM.

How can I automatically use the same version in projectB?

Answer (score 1):

The `compile` scope is not inherited transitively by projects that use your module as a dependency.

To set a transitive dependency (being a BOM or of any other kind) you should use the `api` scope.

However, note that for using the `api` scope, you need to tell Gradle that your project is a library (and not an executable module). To do this, you should add the `java-library` plugin.

Your project A should be defined this way:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
  api platform('com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.2')
  api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
}
```

You can check all the details at the [java-library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) documentation.